# How can you make a case inside a button action performed, based off if another jbutton is chosen in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I have these two methods:

```
    private void bcsButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel<>();

for (Subject s : cCores) {
coreSubjectsList.setModel(model);
model.addElement(bcs.displayCores(s));
}
record1 = new Record(bcs.getCourseName());
ArrayList cores = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(cCores));
record1.enrolCores(cores);

DefaultListModel model2 = new DefaultListModel<>();

for (Major m : BCSMajors) {
majorsList.setModel(model2);
model2.addElement(bcs.displayMajors(m));
}

DefaultListModel model3 = new DefaultListModel<>();
for (Subject s : cEles) {
this.electivesList.setModel(model3);
model3.addElement(bcs.displayElectives(s));
}


}   

private void enrolButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:

String text = this.studNumberField.getText();
int studentNumber = Integer.parseInt(text);
String selection = group.getSelection().getActionCommand();
Student stud1 = new UnderGraduate(this.studentNameTextField.getText(), studentNumber, selection, this.dobField.getText(), "");
if (stud1 instanceof UnderGraduate) {
((UnderGraduate) stud1).writeFileUnderGrad();
record1.setStatus(Record.Status.ACTIVE);
record1.writeRecordFile();
}
  

}
```

For the enrol button, I want to make a case that if the bcsButton is chosen, and I click enrol, it will execute what is inside the enrol method. Because later on I want to make another button called mcsButton, and make two cases, that if mcsButton is chosen it will perform "the enrol code for mcs", and if bcsButton is chosen, it will perform "the enrol code for bcs". Is there any particular way I can do this? Thank you.I've tried using something like:

```
   if(evt.getSource() == bcsButton){
//put my code here
}
```

It doesn't run anything though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and make two cases, that if mcsButton is chosen it will perform "the enrol code for mcs", and if bcsButton is chosen, it will perform "the enrol code for bcs".

You would generally use a `JRadioButton` for this. The user can only select one of two buttons that has been added to the `ButtonGroup`.

Then in your "Enroll" button you check to see which button has been selected and execute the appropriate logic. The ActionListener code would be something like:

```
if (mcsButton.isSelected())
    processMCSEnrol();
else if (bcsButton.isSelected())
    processBCSEnrol();
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) for more information and working examples.

Edit:

You need a variable lets say, `mcsSelected`.

In the ActionListener for the "mcsButton" you add:

```
mcsSelected = true;
```

In the ActionListener for the "bcsButton" you add:

```
mcsSelected = false;
```

In the "Enrol" ActionListener you add:

```
if (mcsSeleced)
    processMCS();
else
    processBCS();
```

Comment: I'm required to use a jButton, is there a way implementing what I need with two jbuttons?

Comment: @TalonRake213,  That is a ridiculous requirement. A JButton has no permanent state. Each button works independent of other buttons on the frame. The user has no indication about what button has been pressed. They can easily forget. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and the idea. I really appreciate it.